# Android GridView Square Layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gridview

I have an Android Activity with a GridView as Layout, and I want to let it look like squares (like the first Screenshot of this App:  [My Study Life](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.virblue.mystudylife)). Can I specify this in the Layout File?

This is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</GridView>
```

Comment: Your link is not working.

Comment: Like the first Screenshot of this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.virblue.mystudylife

Answer (score 0):

The square behavior is handled by the grid items and not the `GridView` itself.

Google provides an example on how to load bitmaps effectively and shows them in a `GridView` with squared views.

A good start would be to check out the sample from http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: I don't understand these Dev Doc, because I cant find the any specification / functions for a square Grid View. Additionally I dont want to show Bitmaps in my GridView, only texts. Is there any function / specification I can call?